# Google Data Studio crashes Ubuntu 20.04 with nvidia drivers

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, crash, brave

I'm not sure if this is the right channel to ask this, but here it is:

I have a brand new laptop and Ubuntu install (less than 2 months) with nvidia drivers that always worked great, but recently I opened a report in Google Data Studio and, after a few minutes fiddling around it, the OS completely crashes and reboots. It already happened three times in the last 30 minutes, so it can't be a coincidence.

`apport-cli` outputs "No pending crash reports.".
`dmesg | grep error` outputs one line:

> EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none

Here is a piece of `/var/log/syslog`. The crash was around 10:25, April 12: https://pastebin.com/AKNdiiZ9

Here is my system:
Acer Nitro 5 with AMD Ryzen 7 4800H and Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650, kernel 5.13.0-39-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu, nvidia driver version 510.54. I opened the Data Studio report in Brave Browser (launched with right click -> Launch using dedicated graphics card)

Comment: A crash should result in some details being recorded to `/var/log/syslog`. Could you [edit] your question to include any records from around the time of the crash? Could you also include the output of `free -m` and the amount of RAM you have installed? This may be a memory exhaustion issue 

Comment: I put the syslog in the answer. Also, I don't think it's a memory exhaustion issue, I have 16 Gb and was using aroung 6 at the time of the crashes